# CS7036 Visual Studo No Formal Parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have been trying to write a basic Comic book management application using C# and windows forms. But I have constantly been receiving error

> CS7036- There are no arguments given that corresponds to the required formal parameter.

Could any one advise me on how to overcome this as it has had me stumped for sometime now?

### Add Comics Form Code

```
    public partial class AddComic : Form
   {
    public AddComic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static void main()
    {
        ComicClass comic1 = new ComicClass();
        comic1.SetTitle("IronMan");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create New Comic Book
        ComicClass newComic;
        newComic = new ComicClass();

        if (txtTitle.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetTitle(txtTitle.Text);
        }

        if (txtPublisher.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetPublisher(txtPublisher.Text);
        }

        if (txtAuthor.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetAuthor(txtAuthor.Text);
        }

        if (txtIllustrator.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetIllustrator(txtIllustrator.Text);
        }

        if (txtIssueNumber.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetIssueNumber(txtIssueNumber.Text);
        }
        if (txtReleaseDate.Text != "")
        {
            newComic.SetReleaseDate(txtReleaseDate.Text);
        }
        try
        {
            if (txtCost.Text != "")
            {
                newComic.SetCost(Convert.ToDouble(txtCost.Text));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Cost Must be formated 00.00");
            return;
        }




    }
  }
```

### ComicClass

```
class ComicClass
{
private String sTitle;
private String sPublisher;
private String sAuthor;
private String sIllustrator;
private String sIssueNumber;
private String sReleaseDate;
private double dCost;


//Accessor & Mutator for the Title//
public String GetTitle()
{
    return sTitle;
}

public void SetTitle(String psTitle)
{
    sTitle = psTitle;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Publisher//
public String GetPublisher()
{
    return sPublisher;
}

public void SetPublisher(String psPublisher)
{
    sPublisher = psPublisher;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Author//
public String GetAuthor()
{
    return sAuthor;
}

public void SetAuthor(String psAuthor)
{
    sAuthor = psAuthor;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Illustrator//
public String GetIllustrator()
{
    return sIllustrator;
}

public void SetIllustrator(String psIllustrator)
{
    sIllustrator = psIllustrator;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Issue Number//
public String GetIssueNumber()
{
    return sIssueNumber;
}

public void SetIssueNumber(String psIssueNumber)
{
    sIssueNumber = psIssueNumber;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Release Date//
public String GetReleaseDate()
{
    return sReleaseDate;
}

public void SetReleaseDate(String psReleaseDate)
{
    sReleaseDate = psReleaseDate;
}

//Accessor & Mutator for the Cost//  
public double GetCost()
{
    return dCost;
}

public void SetCost(double pdCost)
{
    dCost = pdCost;
}

//Constructor//
public ComicClass  (String psTitle,String psAuthor, String psIllustrator, String psIssueNumber, String psRelaseDate, double pdCost)
{
    sTitle = psTitle;
    sAuthor = psAuthor;
    sIllustrator = psIllustrator;
    sIssueNumber = psIssueNumber;
    sReleaseDate = psRelaseDate;
    dCost = pdCost;

}

static void main(string [] args)
{




    }
```

Comment: Read the error message.  You need to pass parameters.

Comment: how about indicating which line the error points at

Comment: You can't do this `ComicClass comic1 = new ComicClass();` if your ComicClass' constructor has parameters.  You have to do `... = new ComicClass(yada, yada, yada...`

Comment: btw: you may want to read about [c# properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) instead of writing your own `Get...` and `Set..` methods

Answer (score 1):

here

```
public ComicClass  (String psTitle,String psAuthor, String psIllustrator, String psIssueNumber, String psRelaseDate, double pdCost)
```

you say that the constructor takes a big list of arguments. Here

```
 ComicClass comic1 = new ComicClass();
```

you invoke it without those paramters

You need

```
ComicClass comic1 = new ComicClass("x","y","z",...);
```

BTW, calling a class XXXClass is a classic anti-pattern, just call it Comic

And use c# properties, not your own Get and Set methods

you Comic class should look like this

```
public class Comic
{
public string Title {get;set;}
public string Author {get;set;}
...
}
```

now you can do

```
   var comic = new Comic
    {
       Title = "xxxx",
       Author = "yy"
    };
...
    comic.Title = "Changed my mind"
```

Comment: Thanks, that had been bugging me for a while but had not been able to find the resources on line in that specific context.

Comment: and please please dont do hungarian in c# (sTitle, dPrice, ...)

Comment: I'm afraid i'm unsure as to what you mean by Hungarian?

Comment: prefixing a variable name with its type